# Add the value of a variable to a HashTable as the key

Tags: powershell, hashtable, powershell-5.0

**PowerShell V5 Windows 10**

For example, the variable `$EmployeeID` contains the string `testValue`, and I want to simply use the value of the previous variable inside the `$HastTable.Add()` function. It would look like this:

```
$HashTable.Add($EmployeeID, 'some_value')
```

*Except of course that does not work, but hopefully I am clear in what I want to achieve.*

With that, I can then access the value like I normally do:

```
$var = $HashTable.testValue
```

Comment: You wan't the value of the previously added variable to be the key of the next entry in the hashtable - but what should the value of the next entry be? Where does the values come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it *right* and should be able to access the key wihtout any issues (you only don't get auto completion this way):

```
$HashTable = @{ }
$EmployeeID = "testValue"
$HashTable.Add($EmployeeID, 'some_value')
$var = $HashTable.testValue
$var
```

**Output:**

```
some_value
```

Comment: Whoops, so I was correct after all, must be something else going on in my script because it throws an error, but that's a different matter and I'll deal with that. Thank you.